# Displaying messages after array limit is exceeded in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to display a message after entering a series of numbers in an array 
and I am trying to print the array after the array limit is exceeded. The input in the array is working fine but displaying the messages after the array limit is exceeded is not working

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] values = new int[10];
        {
            System.out.print("please insert a value : "  );
            for( i = 0 ;i < values.length; i++)
            {                   
                try 
                {
                    values[i] = input.nextInt();    
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    System.out.println("The value you have input is not a valid integer");
                }

            }
            if (i> values.length)
            {
                 System.out.println("Array limit exceeded");
                 for(i =0 ;i<values.length ; i++)
                 {
                     System.out.println(values[i]);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't reaching the `if` condition. When you exit the loop, `i = values.length`.

Answer (score 3):

After this:

```
        for( i = 0 ;i < values.length; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                values[i] = input.nextInt();    
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("The value you have input is not a valid integer");
            }

        }
```

your `i` is equal to `values.length` because you don't change it in the `for` loop body. It will have the first integer value ( >= 0 ) that doesn't satisfy the condition and this is `values.length`.

This is why the following condition is never `true`:

```
        if (i> values.length)
```

So, the array limit will never be exceeded.

**Suggestion:**

I suppose that you want something like this:

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int[] values = new int[10];
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("Insert a value : ");
                try {
                    values[i] = input.nextInt();
                    i++;
                } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
                    System.out.println("The value is not a valid integer");
                    input.next();
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("Array limit exceeded");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you try to add the 11<sup>th</sup> element, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.